# TSQL UNPIVOT for months + year column to date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have this table structure in SQL Server 2008:

Columns: PersonID, DOSE1, DOSE2, DOSE3, ..... DOSE12, YEAR

example row:  123, 0.1,   0.0,   0.5,   ..... 0.7,    2008

So basically I have a column for each month, and then a column year.

And the rows contain dose values for each of these months of that year.

My desired output is:

Columns: PersonId, BeginDate, EndDate, Dose

BeginDate and EndDate would be derived from the DOSEx columns, and the year.
So say the year is 2008, the DOSE1 column would give me a BeginDate of 01/01/2008 end the EndDate should be 31/01/2008 23:59

For DOSE4 it's the month of April, so BeginDate should be 01/04/2008 and EndDate 30/04/2008 23:59

Any way to achieve this using TSQL ? I have a suspicion I should be using UNPIVOT, but not really sure how to get there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

TJ

Comment: And can you explain more how the Begindate and enddate is calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  PersonId, 
            CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST([YEAR] AS VARCHAR(4))+RIGHT('0'+SUBSTRING(Months,5,2),2)+'01') BeginDate,
            Dose
    FROM YourTable A
    UNPIVOT(Dose FOR Months IN (DOSE1,DOSE2,DOSE3,DOSE4,DOSE5,DOSE6,DOSE7,DOSE8,DOSE9,DOSE10,DOSE11,DOSE12)) UP
)

SELECT PersonId, BeginDate, DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,BeginDate)) EndDate, Dose
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works, the only minor adjustment I made was to the date conversion part to make sure it is using the right locale: CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/' + SUBSTRING(months,5,2) + '/' + CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4)), 102) AS BeginDate

Comment: @tjeuten - Glad it worked. In any case the format `YYYYMMDD` is the only `VARCHAR` date format that doesn't depend on the locale, its ISO and it its not ambiguous.